# Here maps iOS sdk avoid particular roads

Tags: navigation, here-api

I was working on a navigation app for iOS, using here maps sdk. 
I wanted to get a route from source and destination by avoiding a particular road in between. I checked with the routing api where it provides me an option like avoid area. Is there anything same in iOS sdk of here maps. If not, how can I use the response from routing api to draw a polyline or navigation in iOS.
 Can anyone of you here please help me on finishing this task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MobileSDK side, you can use the dynamic penalties.

When setting up the `NMACoreRouter` for route calculation, set the `dynamicPenalty` property, that can penalize (`addPenalty`) or ban (`addBannedArea`) areas or concrete road elements.

Link to the iOS API reference: https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/interfacenmadynamicpenalty.html